# How to remove points of the same colors that go in a row in UIImage?

Tags: swift, algorithm, uiimage

I have a function that removes consecutive dots of the same color.

```
 func processImage(point: CGPoint, completion: @escaping ((UIImage?, [CGPoint])) -> Void) {
    guard var image = self.imageView?.image, var cgImage = image.cgImage else {
        completion((nil, []))
        return
    }
    
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async { [weak self] in
        
        guard let self = self else {
            completion((nil, []))
            return
        }
        var processedImage = image
        var processedCGImage = cgImage
        
        var targetPoints: [CGPoint] = []
        if point.x >= 0 && point.x < image.size.width && point.y >= 0 && point.y < image.size.height {
            var targetColor = cgImage.colors(at: point)
            var processedPoints: [CGPoint] = []
            targetPoints.append(point)
            processedPoints.append(point)
            
            while !processedPoints.isEmpty {
                guard let firstPoint = processedPoints.first else {
                    completion((image, targetPoints))
                    return
                }

                let pointX = firstPoint.x
                let pointY = firstPoint.y

                processedPoints.removeFirst()
                if pointX - 1 >= 0, pointX - 1 <= image.size.width, cgImage.colors(at: CGPoint(x: pointX - 1, y: pointY)).isEqual(color: targetColor), !targetPoints.contains(.init(x: pointX - 1, y: pointY)) {
                    let newPoint = CGPoint(x: pointX - 1, y: pointY)
                    processedPoints.append(newPoint)
                    targetPoints.append(newPoint)
                }

                if pointX + 1 <= image.size.width, pointX + 1 >= 0, cgImage.colors(at: CGPoint(x: pointX + 1, y: pointY)).isEqual(color: targetColor), !targetPoints.contains(.init(x: pointX + 1, y: pointY)) {
                    let newPoint = CGPoint(x: pointX + 1, y: pointY)
                    processedPoints.append(newPoint)
                    targetPoints.append(newPoint)
                }

                if pointY - 1 >= 0, pointY - 1 <= image.size.height, cgImage.colors(at: CGPoint(x: pointX, y: pointY - 1)).isEqual(color: targetColor), !targetPoints.contains(.init(x: pointX, y: pointY - 1)) {
                    let newPoint = CGPoint(x: pointX, y: pointY - 1)
                    processedPoints.append(newPoint)
                    targetPoints.append(newPoint)
                }

                if pointY + 1 <= image.size.width, pointY + 1 >= 0, cgImage.colors(at: CGPoint(x: pointX, y: pointY - 1)).isEqual(color: targetColor), !targetPoints.contains(.init(x: pointX, y: pointY + 1)) {
                    let newPoint = CGPoint(x: pointX, y: pointY + 1)
                    processedPoints.append(newPoint)
                    targetPoints.append(newPoint)
                }
             }
            
            print(targetPoints)
            DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                var image: UIImage?
                targetPoints.forEach {
                    image = self?.processByPixel(in: image ?? processedImage, byPoint: $0)
                }
                completion((image, targetPoints))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For example, we have a point with coordinates x-50 y-50 having a black color, I go through all the neighboring points and if they are also black, then I add them to the deletion queue.
I have a problem, my function is taking a very long time because it has a very large number of iterations. Is there a way to speed up this feature?

Comment: Are you sure you want qos: .background? Maybe .userInitiated would be more appropriate?

Comment: @de. no it doesn't really matter, i just tried it

Comment: From information provided cannot say anything definite, but here are 3 clues: 1 - use profiler to identify the slow parts of your function (you literally can measure each portion of the function to see what is slow; I would especially suspect `cgImage.colors(at: point)` - it's not a built-in function so I wonder if it's efficient). 2 - normally the strategy is to get pixel array from CGImage, and loop on that array (here's the example: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/changing-and-replacing-colors-in-images-using-swift-d338ba79bd04);

Comment: 3 - or, if you intend to process bigger images, you will have to use a framework like Accelerate or Metal, which allows to use GPU for image processing, and does a multi-threaded processing automatically.